# Amazon Selling Partner API 403 - Signature Error

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, cryptojs, amazon-selling-partner-api

I'm trying to make a request to the Amazon Selling Partner API (node.js/Lambda) but I currently always get a 403 error back. I have plugged the same credentials and access token into Postman and the request works fine. I believe that there must be an error when I'm calculating the signature for the request, but I can't see anything wrong.

I'm calculating the signature as follows:

```
function constructCanonicalRequest(accessToken, dateTime) {
    let canonical = [];
    canonical.push('GET');
    canonical.push('/fba/outbound/2020-07-01/fulfillmentOrders/FBATestOrder-1');
    canonical.push('');
    canonical.push('host:' + 'sandbox.sellingpartnerapi-na.amazon.com');
    canonical.push('x-amz-access-token:' + accessToken);
    canonical.push('x-amz-date:' + dateTime);
    canonical.push('');
    canonical.push('host;x-amz-access-token;x-amz-date');
    canonical.push(crypto.SHA256(''));

    let canonicalRequest = canonical.join('\n');
    let canonicalRequestHash = crypto.SHA256(canonicalRequest);

    return canonicalRequestHash
};

function constructStringToSign(dateTime, date, canonicalRequestHash) {
    let stringToSign = [];
    stringToSign.push('AWS4-HMAC-SHA256')
    stringToSign.push(dateTime);
    stringToSign.push(date + '/' + 'us-east-1' + '/' + 'execute-api' + '/aws4_request');
    stringToSign.push(canonicalRequestHash);
    
    return stringToSign.join('\n');
};

function constructSignature(date, iamSecret, stringToSign) {
    let kDate = crypto.HmacSHA256(date, 'AWS4' + iamSecret);
    let kRegion = crypto.HmacSHA256('us-east-1', kDate);
    let kService = crypto.HmacSHA256('execute-api', kRegion);
    let kSigning = crypto.HmacSHA256('aws4_request', kService);

    let signature = crypto.HmacSHA256(stringToSign, kSigning).toString(crypto.enc.Hex);

    return signature
};
```

The rest of the function is:

```
        let dateTimeISO = new Date().toISOString();
        let dateTime = dateTimeISO.replace(/(\.\d{3})|\W/g,'');
        let date = dateTime.split('T')[0];

        let canonicalRequestHash = constructCanonicalRequest(accessToken, dateTimeISO);
        let stringToSign = constructStringToSign(dateTime, date, canonicalRequestHash);
        let signature = constructSignature(date, iamSecret, stringToSign);

        let authHeader = 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=' + iamId + '/' + date + '/' + 'us-east-1' + '/execute-api/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-access-token;x-amz-date, Signature=' + signature

        console.log(authHeader);

        let amazonUrl = "https://sandbox.sellingpartnerapi-na.amazon.com/fba/outbound/2020-07-01/fulfillmentOrders/FBATestOrder-1";
        const amazonResponse = await fetch(amazonUrl, {
            method: 'get',
            headers: {
                'Authorization':authHeader,
                'Content-Type':'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                'host':'sandbox.sellingpartnerapi-na.amazon.com',
                'x-amz-access-token':accessToken,
                'user-agent': 'My Selling Tool/2.0 (Language=JS;Platform=Node)',
                'x-amz-date':dateTime,                
            }
        });
```

I have also tried using multiple difference crypto libraries to see if the HMAC creation is the problem, but this hasn't fixed anything.

Answer (score 0):

I have my access working in C#.  There is a Java library available on GitHub:
https://github.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-docs/blob/main/guides/en-US/developer-guide/SellingPartnerApiDeveloperGuide.md
I just followed the instructions there, though there is a deficiency in the C# lib about assume role, that is in the java lib.

Comment: Yeah I followed this guide step by step but still haven't been able to make a valid request.

Comment: Have you compared the output at each stage, canonical request, etc, between your code and what you are doing in Postman?

Comment: Yep everything seems to match - the only thing that could be different is the signature as it's created from multiple hashes

Comment: Maybe step back a bit and get it working in Java.  Then build from there?